# Can I make my app running on background without any UI

Tags: react-native, background-task, mobile-development

I am working on an app based on NFC tech. When my app runs, I don't want to show users any UI, I just want it to work in background, run the algorithm and send notification. Is there any way I can do this with React Native(currently Android)?

Comment: I don't think it is possible and also user friendly to create an app with no UI whatsoever. I'd at least create a simple view where to user can see that the app is up and running.

Comment: But this app is a task app. User will get a feedback with a notification based on app's algorithm